# Writing Absolute Value Inequality Equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$(1)$ Write an algebraic expression to represent each verbal expression.

$(a)$ Numbers that are at least $4$ units away from $-5$

$(b)$ Numbers that are no more than $\frac {3}{8}$ unit from $1$

$(c)$ Numbers that are at least $6$ units, but no more than $10$ units from $2$

I'm kinda confused by how I should represent "at least" and "no more than" with inequality signs. I'm also baffled on where to start with $(c)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us clarify your doubts:

*"at least"* means that you quantity is *greater than or equal to* the given quantity. For example, numbers  that are at least $4$ units away from $-5$ are numbers whose difference from $-5$ is *greater than or equal to* $4$. So, the difference between any integer $x$ and $-5$ is $|x - (-5)|$, because the distance between the two of them is always a positive number, even if the difference is negative. This has to be *greater than or equal to* $4$, so the expression is $|x-(-5)| \geq 4$, which translates  to $|x+5| \geq 4$.

Next,*"no more than"* means that you quantity is *less than or equal to* the given quantity. For example, numbers  that are no more than $\frac{3}{8}$ units away from $1$ are numbers whose difference from $1$ is *less than or equal to* $\frac{3}{8}$. So, the difference between any integer $x$ and $1$ is $|x - 1|$, because the distance between the two of them is always a positive number, even if the difference is negative. This has to be *less than or equal to* $\frac{3}{8}$, so the expression is $|x-1| \leq \frac{3}{8}$.

Finally, the last one is a mixture of the two. Here, (I'll leave you to verify) we get first that $|x-2| \geq 6$, then that $|x-2| \leq 10$. This can be succinctly written as $6 \leq |x-2| \leq 10$.